# Make Hamcrest to match a key or value in a Map

Tags: java, collections, hamcrest

I wrote this test program for Hamcrest and Map to use Hamcrest Matchers.
This program use Hamcrest as standalone (does not use JUnit).
Why none of the output is true (matched)?
How to modify this test program so that a key or value in a Map is matched (output is true)?

```
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    import java.util.stream.Stream;
    
    import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
    import org.hamcrest.collection.IsMapContaining;
    
    public class TestMap {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        
            Map<String, Integer> map = Stream.of(new Object[][] { 
                { "data1", 1 }, 
                { "data2", 2 }, 
            }).collect(Collectors.toMap(data -> (String) data[0], data -> (Integer) data[1]));
    
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Matchers.hasKey(\"data1\") " + Matchers.hasKey("data1").matches("data1"));
                System.out.println("Matchers.hasValue(1) " + Matchers.hasValue(1).matches(1));
                System.out.println("IsMapContaining.hasKey(\"data1\") " + IsMapContaining.hasKey("data1").matches("data1"));
                System.out.println("IsMapContaining.hasValue(1) " + IsMapContaining.hasValue(1).matches(1));
                System.out.println("IsMapContaining.hasEntry(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()) " + IsMapContaining.hasEntry(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
            }
        }
    }
```

The output is:

```
Matchers.hasKey("data1") false
Matchers.hasValue(1) false
IsMapContaining.hasKey("data1") false
IsMapContaining.hasValue(1) false
IsMapContaining.hasEntry(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()) map containing ["data2"-><2>]
Matchers.hasKey("data1") false
Matchers.hasValue(1) false
IsMapContaining.hasKey("data1") false
IsMapContaining.hasValue(1) false
IsMapContaining.hasEntry(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()) map containing ["data1"-><1>]
```

Comment: did the answer help you, btw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will only explain the first one, you can understand the rest on your own (and btw this is not entirely your fault here).

What do you think happens here:

```
Matchers.hasKey("data1").matches("data1")
```

Let's read the documentation of `hasKey`:

> Creates a matcher for `java.util.Map`s matching when the examined `java.util.Map` contains at least one key that is equal to the specified key.

Now, let's read the documentation for `matches`:

> This method matches against Object, instead of the generic type T. This is because the caller of the Matcher does not know at runtime what the type is (because of type erasure with Java generics). **It is down to the implementations to check the correct type**.

Ideally, you want the *compiler* (`javac`) to only let you specify a `Map` in `matches` (not a `"data1"` String). You did, after all, say that you want to compare `hasKey` for a `Map`, didn't you?  But as said in the documentation : "It is down to the implementations to check the correct type", `javac` can not simply do that (this is a limitation); and you need to do that on your own.

In simpler words, this `Matchers.hasKey("data1").matches("data1")` should not even compile, but because this is the way `javac` works (and because `hamcrest` designed their code like this), this does compile, with a wrong type.

The solution is trivial:

```
System.out.println("Matchers.hasKey(\"data1\") " + Matchers.hasKey("data1").matches(map));
```

Notice that `matches(map)`...